# C# '\n' saved in different bytes than expected

Tags: c#, string

If I save this string to a text file;

> Hello this \n is a test message

The \n character is saved as HEX [5C 6E] I would like to have it saved as [0A].

I believe this is an encoding issue?

I am using;

```
// 1252 is a variable in the application
Encoding codePage = Encoding.GetEncoding("1252");
Byte[] bytes = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("Hello this \\n is a test message");
Byte[] encodedBytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, codePage , bytes);
```

All this is inside a FileStream scope and uses fs.Write to write the encodedBytes into the file.

I have tried to use \r\n but had the same result.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

The string is being read from a tsv file and placed into an string array. The string being read has the "\n" in it.

To read the string I use a `StreamReader reader` and split at \t

Comment: Then why did you define it as a ``\`` + `n`? Use `"\n"`: `"Hello this \n is a test message"`

Comment: `'\'` is 5C. `'n'` is 6E. (`"\\"` produces the backslash character.)

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. In what way could this question be improved?

Comment: @Bathsheba Not my vote, but if the question asks about the string `"Hello this \n is a test message"`, but the code in the question *actually* has the string `"Hello this \\n is a test message"`, and changing that `\\n` to `\n` would do exactly what the OP expects, it's hard to see what the *real* question is, if there is one.

Comment: @DavidG The first line is about writing to a text file, not about reading from one. The question doesn't say where the string is coming from, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At execution time, your string contains a backslash character followed by an `n`. They're encoded *exactly as they should be*. If you actually want a linefeed character, you shouldn't be escaping the backslash in your code:

```
Byte[] bytes = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("Hello this \n is a test message");
```

That string literal uses `\n` to represent U+000A, the linefeed character. At execution time, the string won't contain a backslash or an `n` - it will *only* contain the linefeed.

However, your code is already odd in that if you want to get the encoded form of a string, there's no reason to go via UTF-8:

```
byte encodedBytes = codePage.GetBytes("Hello this \n is a test message");
```

Comment: Thank you. I was assuming the problem was with how I was encoding an not with how I was reading the string.